# Visual Studio 2010 freezes loading project with 'Processing Request... Loading System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Just today one of my C# (.NET 4.0) projects began refusing to open, freezing with the following dialog:

[image]

It's a C# Website Project Template, and it uses Entity Framework. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good 'solution' - but I pulled the code out into a new solution and it worked fine. Unfortunately I ran out of time to figure out a good fix for this -